# Why composer.json is modified after "composer install" command?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am currently working on a Laravel 5.8 project that I have just cloned from our company's Gitlab. I ran `composer install` and after that when I run `git status` it lists `composer.json` as a modified file.

I thought that `composer install` does not modify `composer.json` file.

I think that if I commit this file, then the remote server can not merge the new composer file with the old one.

What should I do?

Comment: Please run this command `git stash` for revert your changes.

Comment: @VikasKatariya you mean I just install required packages and then stash the newly generated composer.json file?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Comment: Can you share more details? What's the difference between the local file and the one in the repository?

Comment: Did you by any chance open `composer.json` in an IDE/editor? Maybe different linefeeds have been saved?

Comment: do you have composer.lock file in your working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Composer install will not modify `composer.json`. But there are some circumstances where it can be changed, although I don't know about any that would happen without user input.

The one I can think of as of now, is the setting `config.allow-plugins`.

If you clone a project created with Composer < 2.2.0, this option wouldn't exist on the configuration file.

If you now run a version of Composer > 2.2.0, and if this project includes composer plugins (some that come to mind are `composer/package-versions-deprecated`, `symfony/flex`, `symfony/runtime`, and more), you'd get a few prompts asking you to authorize plugins.

Like so:

> bamarni/composer-bin-plugin contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
> Do you trust "bamarni/composer-bin-plugin" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?]

The different options stand for:

Choosing `y`es or `n`o, would end up modifying your `composer.json` adding this configuration.

> I think that if I commit this file, then the remote server can not merge the new composer file with the old one.

Git has no problems merging this kind of change.

> What should I do?

Talk with someone at your company. Run `git diff composer.json` to check the changes, and verify with someone if you should push those changes upstream or not. If not, simply run `git restore composer.json`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem as you said was for allowing plugin. I downgraded my composer to version 1 and tried to do composer install with it.